# jQuery AJAX document trigger?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, triggers

My jQuery code:

```
$('.Img').click(function() {
    alert('Test');
});

$().ready(function() {
    $.ajax( {
        type     : 'POST',
        url      : 'Post.php',
        success  : function(Response) {
          $('#Response').html(Response);
        }
    }
});
```

My HTML code:

```
<div id="Response"></div>
<img class="Img" src="blank.gif" /> [Click Trigger]
```

My PHP code:

```
echo '<img class="Img" src="blank.gif" />'; [Ajax from response]
```

why this image does not trigger from AJAX response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) here, like this:

```
$('.Img').live('click', function(){
 alert('Test');
});
```

It doesn't work currently because `$('.Img')` doesn't find the `<img>` to attach a `click` handler to...it didn't exist then, not until the ajax call loaded it, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) will listen for the click appropriately, even if the element is added later.